# Postgres Multiple Column Values of Same Data Sub Query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a postgres database from redshift and trying to run the following query to get the data looking right and I am struggling.

Database table looks like:
created_at,url,status

Where I am struggling is I want to run a report that shows me the total number of times it finds any url directory, but then the 2nd column would show me how many times the status was 301, or 404, or 200...etc?

```
select regexp_replace(url, '^https://[^.]+\.vecteezy\.com/([^/]+).*$', '$1') urlpath,count(*) total_crawls, (select count(*) from googlebot_logs  where status='301') from googlebot_logs
where created_at > '2019-12-01' AND
url like 'https://www.vecteezy.com%'
group by urlpath
order by total_crawls desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FILTER expression on the aggregate function.  For example:

```
COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status='301') AS "301 count"
```

To adapt it to your query, you could run:

```
SELECT
  regexp_replace(url, '^https://[^.]+\.vecteezy\.com/([^/]+).*$', '$1') urlpath,
  count(*) total_crawls,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE status='301') AS "301_count",
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE status='404') AS "404_count",
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE status IN ('401','403')) AS "found_but_not_allowed",
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE status LIKE '2%') AS "success",
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE status LIKE '4%') AS "client_errors"
FROM
  googlebot_logs
WHERE
  created_at > '2019-12-01' AND
  url LIKE 'https://www.vecteezy.com%'
  GROUP BY urlpath
  ORDER BY total_crawls DESC;
```

You can change the filter condition to an IN clause too if you want to check for multiple values.

Disclosure: I am an EnterpriseDB employee.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess I can't figure out how to construct the query with your examples. Do you have a similar example?

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer with an example for your case.

Comment: Thanks Thom when I run that I get the following: Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 4:   count(*) FILTER (status='301') AS '301_count',

Comment: Looks like I omitted the WHERE keyword.  Updated in answer.

Comment: Still erroring out Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 4:   count(*) FILTER (WHERE status='301') AS "301_count",

Comment: I've tested the clause on some test data and it works, so not sure what could be causing that.  If you get rid of all the other count(*) entries, and remove the comma from the end of the line for "301_count", do you still get the error?  I guess I should also check which version you are using.  You will need at least version 9.4 for this to work.

Comment: It still errors after removing all the other counts. I assume you are asking what version of postgres we are using, and it says PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.11420